# Correct type declaration for method with NgRx ActionCreator as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

There is an action, created using NgRx createAction() method:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const Login = createAction(
  '[Login] Login',
  props <{email: string, password: string}>()
);
```

I want to create service with a method which takes action created with createAction() method as argument and returns an object with this action as one of its properties.

Now it looks like:

```
import { ActionCreator, ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store';

interface ActionWithProgress<T> {
  progress: boolean;
  action: T;
}

export class ListenerService {
  constructor(private dispatcher: ActionsSubject) { }

  public isInProgress(currentAction: ActionCreator): Observable<ActionWithStatus<ActionCreator>> {
    return this.dispatcher.pipe(
      filter((action: Action) => action.type === currentAction.type),
      map((action: Action) => ({progress: true, action: currentAction}))
    );
  }
}
```

But in this case TypeScript loses type of action property and it's impossible to handle errors like this:

```
this.loginEmail$ = this.listenerService
  .isInProgress(LoginActions.Login)
  .pipe(
    // Want to see here TypeScript error: property 'name' doesn't exist in Login action
    map((actionWithProgress) => actionWithProgress.action.name)
  );
```

I tried to explore:

```
import { ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
```

With its declaration:

```
export declare function ofType<E extends Extract<U, {
    type: T1;
}>, AC extends ActionCreator<string, Creator>, T1 extends string | AC, U extends Action = Action, V = T1 extends string ? E : ReturnType<Extract<T1, AC>>>(t1: T1): OperatorFunction<U, V>;
```

But it seems to be overloaded to be backward compatible with old versions of NgRx.

So I need the correct type for this method to prevent losing action property type.

Comment: Have you looked at how they do it in the example app? https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app/src/app/auth

I think you'll find the complete code there for what you want to do
In the core part they use the selectors such as logged in etc...

Comment: @Curator There are now such cases in example app and it is not about selectors. I need to create function which can take any Action, and return object with this Action. And it has to be typed correctly.

Comment: I don't see a prop 'name' to be set yet you are trying to access it in map operator. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EvgenyFedorenko You are right, in this case I want to have TypeScript error if this property doesn't exist. And I want to see some advices in IDE with correct properties for this action, like 'email' and 'password'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  isInProgress<
    T1 extends ActionCreator,
    V = ReturnType<T1>
  >(currentAction: T1): Observable<ActionWithProgress<V>>

  isInProgress(currentAction: ActionCreator): Observable<ActionWithProgress<Action>> {
    return this.dispatcher.pipe(
      filter((action: Action) => action.type === currentAction.type),
      map((action: Action) => ({ progress: true, action: action }))
    );
  }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. But one more question about this, how to use this type for several methods in my Angular service, without code duplication?